# Modifying XML structure based on Condition in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to modify the incoming XML structure based on key field value, please help me to achieve this as I am new into XSL (XSLT 2)
In the source file, **/G_HL/S_HL/D_735 = T** appearing first and then **/G_HL/S_HL/D_735 = I** appearing.

Requirement is each **/G_HL/S_HL/D_735 = I** should appear after each **/G_HL/S_HL/D_735 = T** when //D_350 value is matching.

**Source XML**

```
<G_HL>
    <S_HL>
        <D_735>T</D_735>
    </S_HL>
    <S_PO4>
        <D_65>0.000</D_65>
        <D_350>000010</D_350>
    </S_PO4>
    <S_MAN>
        <D_88>GM</D_88>
    </S_MAN>
</G_HL>
<G_HL>
    <S_HL>
        <D_735>T</D_735>
    </S_HL>
    <S_PO4>
        <D_65>0.000</D_65>
        <D_350>000020</D_350>
    </S_PO4>
    <S_MAN>
        <D_88>GM</D_88>
    </S_MAN>
</G_HL>
<G_HL>
    <S_HL>
        <D_735>I</D_735>
    </S_HL>
    <S_LIN>
        <D_350>000010</D_350>
        <D_235>BP</D_235>
    </S_LIN>
    <S_SN1>
        <D_355>EA</D_355>
    </S_SN1>
</G_HL>
<G_HL>
    <S_HL>
        <D_735>I</D_735>
    </S_HL>
    <S_LIN>
        <D_350>000020</D_350>
        <D_235>BP</D_235>
    </S_LIN>
    <S_SN1>
        <D_355>EA</D_355>
    </S_SN1>
</G_HL>
```

**Expect Structure**

```
<G_HL>
    <S_HL>
        <D_735>T</D_735>
    </S_HL>
    <S_PO4>
        <D_65>0.000</D_65>
        <D_350>000010</D_350>
    </S_PO4>
    <S_MAN>
        <D_88>GM</D_88>
    </S_MAN>
</G_HL>
<G_HL>
    <S_HL>
        <D_735>I</D_735>
    </S_HL>
    <S_LIN>
        <D_350>000010</D_350>
        <D_235>BP</D_235>
    </S_LIN>
    <S_SN1>
        <D_355>EA</D_355>
    </S_SN1>
</G_HL>
<G_HL>
    <S_HL>
        <D_735>T</D_735>
    </S_HL>
    <S_PO4>
        <D_65>0.000</D_65>
        <D_350>000020</D_350>
    </S_PO4>
    <S_MAN>
        <D_88>GM</D_88>
    </S_MAN>
</G_HL>
<G_HL>
    <S_HL>
        <D_735>I</D_735>
    </S_HL>
    <S_LIN>
        <D_350>000020</D_350>
        <D_235>BP</D_235>
    </S_LIN>
    <S_SN1>
        <D_355>EA</D_355>
    </S_SN1>
</G_HL>
```

Comment: A request for someone to write your code for you is not a legitimate question.

Comment: OK. At least can I get some direction/hints to start with ?

Comment: Sure, use a **key** to resolve the cross-reference.

Answer (score 1):

It's always difficult to infer the general requirements from one example. For example, what happens if there is an "I" element with no matching "T" element?

But for your particular case, I would suggest having a template rule for the T elements of the form

```
<xsl:template match="G_HL[S_HL/D_735='T']">
  <xsl:copy-of select-"."/>
  <xsl:copy-of select-"./G_HL[S_HL/D_735="I" and S_LIN/D_350 = current()/S_P04/D_350"/>
</xsl:template>
```

and then another template rule that skips the I elements:

```
<xsl:template match="G_HL[S_HL/D_735='I']"/>
```

An alternative approach would be to treat the whole thing as a sort operation, sorting the input first by the D_350 value and then (descending) by the D_735 value.

And an observation: whoever designed this XML vocabulary had no idea of the costs (in programmer time and in unnecessary bugs generated) they were adding to the system by using cryptic names instead of meaningful names.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a key?

Comment: (a) Because there are only two elements, so a key is unnecessary, and (b) because the OP appears to be a beginner, and it's best to introduce one concept at a time.

Comment: I don't understand your claim in (a). What difference does it make how many elements there are?

Comment: The only benefit of using a key is performance (and even then, it's only a benefit if the optimiser isn't smart enough to do the indexing itself). And you only start getting a performance benefit if there are more than a couple of dozen elements. Otherwise, the cost of building an index doesn't pay for itself. But my main motivation here was (b).

Comment: I have to disagree. The code using a key is much simpler and easier to read. And we don't how many calls on the key (i.e. how many linked pairs are in the source XML) are expected. As for (b), I believe it's best to steer people towards using keys as early as possible.